# VPN for Home to watch TV on the go

Tags: vpn, android, openvpn, pptp, ipsec

My ISP offers TV on tablets, phones, etc. where I have to use an app, but I still have to have that traffic flow through my modem. What would be the best solution to setting up a VPN for probably just me to watch live TV from anywhere? I have an android phone, but my sister has an iPhone and I have an iPod. Cell phone data usage isn't a problem here, it's more setting up a server with the best solution to watch. I say it's only going to be me because I only have a 2 mbps upload. I might have forgotten something... busy sorting out an issue with YouTube videos not loading. I have OpenVPN for Android on my phone so using HTTPS might work. I'm also looking to put together a server that works as a linux based firewall with iptable rules, is it wise to include it in this box?

Answer (score 1):

For your situation I would recommend [PFSense](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Main_Page), because you didn't mention anything about having a firewall in place, and I would *definitely* put a firewall in place of anything at my house. Also, PFSense has OpenVPN built in, so that is also a plus. It's also free. Other solutions may work also, PFSense is not the only one, but I've had good experiences with it.

You don't necessarily need https as the VPN traffic is already encrypted.

Comment: I have a question, is there anyway I can use a FiOS connection strictly for vpn because of the upload over the 2 mbps I have now and 10 mbps the highest my isp offers. I want to connect the fios from the ont to a vpn server with ethernet, then out to the lan (on a different nic) to be routed out through my current isp. I assume I need a l3 switch and route all traffic on the lan to it, including the lan connection of the vpn server. Can openvpn do this alone or openvpn and iptables? Might say just use FiOS but my family is used to current tv, plus I like the tv app. (How this all started)

Comment: @L37H3L it would be best to ask this question separately on serverfault, but the simple answer is yes, you can use the incoming connection strictly as a vpn if you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a computer at home you can use your own VPN server. One that is easy and has lots and lots of features is the free SoftEther VPN, the data bandwidth and speed is better and faster that OpenVPN protocol. But it can work with the same OpenVPN protocol if you want to, the best of SoftEther is that it works really well on port 443 https, what makes it very hard to block it by firewalls unlike other VPN protocols. You can then access your internet as you were at home,and also,use your home printer, scanner, lan, etc, SoftEther VPN is compatible with several protocols that you can easily config on Android, iOS, Linux, Windows, Mac, etc.